# Webkit Desktop Notifications in IE

Tags: internet-explorer, notifications, desktop

Is there anything similar to the Webkit Desktop Notifications that can be used in IE (i.e. notification appearing above taskbar). I an working on a small project in Chrome using the notifications however it now appears that I may be forced to used IE instead.

The notifications are a pretty integral part of the service so I was wondering in there was anything I could use in IE.

Any ideas? Any version of IE is fine at this point (although IE8 and IE9 solutions most applicable, probably). Also, since this will be deployed on a large number of computers, the easier the deployment, the better.

Comment: In the Intranet zone, you could use the CreatePopup API and paint your window where you want it. In other zones, you can only use that API to overlay the browser content area.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope.  You would need to write your own plug-in to do that.

Answer (score 2):

[HTML5 Desktop Notifications](https://github.com/ttsvetko/HTML5-Desktop-Notifications) is a small library that unifies the HTML5 Notifications APIs across different browsers including IE9 & IE10.

Some limitations:

- Notifications could not be "styled" - Only icon(for some browsers and OS), title and body could be changed.
- IE9+ supports *.ico file types only for an overlay icon. No notification title or notification description. Recommended icon size is 16px x 16px.

[image: IE9 running on Windows 7]

Edit: Here is another resource: http://ukot.github.io/ie_web_notifications/ but I admit I couldn't get their demo working on my IE11 installation.

Comment: It doesn't work for me. Yes, I pinned the site to the task bar, but it didn't help.

Comment: Note that first solution has limitations: (a) XP Desktop Style should be set (W2000 style which I prefer does not work) and (b) if your site has multiple pages - each page should be pinned.

Comment: I did not realize, but second solution requires MSI install!  MSI link is in top-right corner.